# Coherent cohomology of the moduli space of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

> Is $H^i\left(\overline{\mathcal M}_g, \mathcal O_{\overline{\mathcal M}_g}\right)$ nontrivial for any $i>0$ and any $g$?

I was not able to find literature on this after searching for a bit, although I will be quite surprised if there isn't any.

This is a simpler, hopefully easier, version of [my previous, much more specific question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212380/do-modular-forms-show-up-in-the-cohomology-of-moduli-spaces-of-unmarked-curves?noredirect=1#comment526809_212380) Here are the partial results and ideas I have:

Jason Starr pointed out that the coherent cohomology is trivial in the stable range $i <(g-1)/2$ because then the Hodge theory is computed and known to consist only of $(p,p)$ classes.

This cohomology group will also be trivial for very small $g$ when $\overline{\mathcal M}_g$ is rational or unirational. But obviously this obstruction is no longer helpful for $g \geq 24$.

Based on the general maxim "when in doubt, compute the Euler characteristic" one might try to produce a positive answer by proving $\chi_a(\overline{\mathcal M}_g) \neq 1$. But it is not at all obvious how to compute this. I guess a proof that $\chi_a(\overline{\mathcal M}_g) =1$ for all $g$ would provide some evidence for a negative answer.

But surely this must be known...

Comment: Do we know the Hodge symmetries for the Deligne-Mumford stack $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$?  I find it easier to think about $H^0(\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g,\Omega^p_{\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g})$ than $H^q(\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g,\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g})$.  There has been an intense analysis of the metric properties of the tangent bundle of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ by, among others, Kefeng Liu -- Xiaofeng Sun -- S.-T. Yau.  Do we even know whether $H^0(\mathcal{M}_g,\Omega^p_{\mathcal{M}_g})$ is nonzero?

Comment: @JasonStarr I think that the main Weil cohomology theories all behave the same for smooth proper Deligne-Mumford stacks but I'm not completely sure. I'd be happy to hear the answer to that question as well!